# How to filter by a condition on a given level in a Pandas Multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose `df` is the following multi-indexed dataframe:

```
letter      date        number
x           2021-01-01  0             0
                        1             1
            2021-01-02  0             2
                        1             3
            2021-01-04  0             4
                        1             5
y           2021-02-07  0             6
                        1             7
            2021-02-09  0             8
                        1             9
```

**For each** letter, I wish to select only those rows where the date is no more than 2 days after the first.

For `x`, the first date is `2021-01-01`, so all the rows where the date is after `2021-01-03` should be removed.

For `y`, the first date is `2021-02-07`, so all the rows where the date is after `2021-01-09` should be removed.

The desired outcome would be:

```
letter      date        number
x           2021-01-01  0             0
                        1             1
            2021-01-02  0             2
                        1             3
y           2021-02-07  0             6
                        1             7
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That actually looks like a series, so can create a boolean index with [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-transform) and filter dates that are less than 2 days from the first value:

```
df = df[
    df.reset_index('date')
        .groupby('letter')['date']
        .transform(lambda x: x < (x.iat[0] + pd.Timedelta(days=2))).values
]
```

```
letter  date        number
x       2021-01-01  0         0
                    1         1
        2021-01-02  0         2
                    1         3
y       2021-02-07  0         6
                    1         7
dtype: int64
```

---

For each group, transform `date` column into boolean values based on the comparison to `min` date offset by 2 days.

```
df.reset_index('date')
    .groupby('letter')['date']
    .transform(lambda x: x < (x.iat[0] + pd.Timedelta(days=2)))
```

Filter:

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6     True
7     True
8    False
9    False
Name: date, dtype: bool
```

Can also use [`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.min.html) to get distance from earliest date regardless of order:

```
df = df[
    df.reset_index('date')
        .groupby('letter')['date']
        .transform(lambda x: x < (x.min() + pd.Timedelta(days=2))).values
]
```

---

Series/df creation code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'letter': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y'],
    'date': pd.to_datetime(['2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-02',
                            '2021-01-02', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-04',
                            '2021-02-07', '2021-02-07', '2021-02-09',
                            '2021-02-09']),
    'number': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    'value': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
}).set_index(['letter', 'date', 'number']).squeeze().rename(None)
```